# .Net-Core configuration pull connection string wrong provider

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core

I'm trying to setting up environment configuration for my .Net-core 2 application. I have 2 `appSettings` config.

appSettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=staging.com;Database=staging;User Id=staging;Password=pwd"
}
```

appsettings.development.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=staging;User Id=local;Password=pwd"
}
```

In my Startup.cs I have my configuration set like so:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

When I go to grab out the connection string.

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

This is returning the one in **appsettings.json** instead of the **appsettings.development.json**  Yet when I check if this is the development environment `env.IsDevelopment()`  it returns `true`.

How can I grab the proper connection string from my configuration?

Comment: Where do you store the staging configurtion? Into appstettings.staging.json or appsettings.json ?

Comment: Staging is in app setting, localhost is in development, I’m expecting localhost but I’m getting staging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is returning the staging one instead of the development. Yet when I check if this is the development environment `env.IsDevelopment()` it returns `true`.

You are getting the developement configuration because you're still in development environment that is why `env.IsDevelopment()` returns `true`.

To tell ASP.Net Core that you're in a `Staging` environment you need to configure that through your project property and set environment property.

Go to `Debug` tab, then make sure that **Environment variables** section has **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** set to **Staging** like below:

[image]

By doing that `env.IsDevelopment()` will return `false` and `env.IsStaging()` will return `true`. So **appsettings.development.json** will not be included to your configuration.

Because there is no **appsettings.staging.json**, then you will get **appseting.json** settings then the `DefaultConnection` you're looking for.

**Side note :** you should create a separate file **appsettings.staging.json** for Staging envrionment because **appseting.json** should contain only common configurations for all environments. Each environement **appsettings.[environment].json** should add new settings or override the common settings.

**Side note :** make sure the paths for the `ConnectionStrings` section is at the root level

Comment: I’m pretty sure this solves it, I will confirm in the morning. I think I need to separate out my configurations

Comment: Yep it is the best practice to separate per environment.

Comment: thanks, It turns out, this was Connection strings  was nested deeper than it should be and it couldn't find it.

Comment: Hum... Your configuration in your question is correct so we didn't see that issue :)

Comment: yeah, this solved the issue because I found it when I moved everything to appsettings.staging.json, but i figured I'd also document my mistake incase someone else came here and still cant figure it out why